# how to find date of last thursday of the month in php?

Tags: php, date

how to find date of last thursday of the month in php ?

it is for the payment thing. staffs needs to paid on last thursday of the month on which they have submitted invoices. I am having hard time finding out the date of last thursday of month

thanks 
abhinab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP >= 5.3:

```
<?php
$date = strtotime('last thu of this month');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $date);
```

PHP < 5.3:

```
<?php
$date = strtotime(sprintf('+1 month %s %s', date('F'), date('Y')));
while (date('D', $date) !== 'Thu') {
    $date -= 86400;
}

echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s', $date);
```

(didn't find a better way to do this)

Output:

```
30.06.2011 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the first day of the month right after.
2. Walk backwards one day at a time until you hit a Thursday.

Comment: how do I do number one ???   I am ok to find no 2 .. sorry a bit weak with date stuff