# get initial and final dates to INSERT 1 row per month into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the difference between 2 dates, and get the last day of each month to insert data do the database. So if there is 3 months on this data range, it will insert 3 row to the database (one for each month).

What I have now is:

```
$jj = '2007-12-31';
$kk = '2009-12-31';


$begin = new DateTime($jj);
$end = new DateTime($kk);

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('last thursday of next month');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
  echo $dt->format( "Y-m-t\n" );

}
```

This will output the last day of each month of this date range, but now I need to add a new row on a mysql table for each month.

If it helps to understand better my question, this is to save monthly payments, but there will be payments for 3 months, 6 months, 1 year, .... and all the payments will be stored in a monthly basis.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it meant to "**...output the last day of each month...**" or the "**last thursday of [each] month**"? There is a bit of confusion between your question and the code sample.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find date of last thursday of the month in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489096/how-to-find-date-of-last-thursday-of-the-month-in-php)

Comment: The output is the same, but you're right, it must be the last day of each month.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly ... would you not do something like:

```
   $insertSQL = "INSERT INTO <table> (%d, '%s', ...);"; 

    foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
        $payDate = $dt->format( "Y-m-t\n" );
        mysql_query(sprintf($insertSQL, $custID, $payDate, ...);
    }
```

Comment: I've used this code instead, but it will add for example 3 rows with the same date...:

for ($i=1; $i<=$DIFFERENCE-IN-MONTHS-BETWEEN-2-DATES; $i++)
     {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLENAME (..., ..., ...) VALUES ($id, '$value', '$date')") or die ('Error! <br />' .mysql_error()); 
      }

Comment: Were you able to answer your question? The code in your comment here does not appear that it would ever increment the date you are inserting.